# Ranking items through votes

Tags: self-study, ranking, voting-system

I asked participants to rank 10 items based on order of importance (i.e.

- 1=most important
- 10=least important
- 11=not relevant

Now, I want to order the items from most voted important to least important. What statistical method would fit this goal best?